# Updateing the same Database Object from multiple requests at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am currently running into an issue with Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy.

I have some threads running doing some work. When they finished, they post their updates to a route I created.
Updates are just plain strings with a path to a file. This string should be saved in the dictionary with a key and the filepath as the value.

My Model:

```
class Variant(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
   description = db.Column(db.String)
   dynamic_data = db.Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(PickleType), default={})
   plugins = db.Column(MutableList.as_mutable(PickleType), default=[])  # list saved as Json
   bdf_files = db.Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(PickleType), default={})  # dict of Plugins with Bdf_file
   project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.id'), nullable=False)
   deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
   base_variant_name = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)code here
```

I have multiple requests ending at the same time and each want to add a Key to bdf_files. I am using PickleType so I dont have to json parse/load on getting / saving data.

My Route to save the data to the dict. I added some debug to test exactly when its working and when its failing.

```
@app.route("/update_database_objects", methods=['POST'])
def update_database_objects():
    """
    Not yet syncronized way to update Database from multiple Threads.
    :return: HTML Success
    """
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request_json["model_data"] == "variant_bdf_files":
        variant_object = Variant.query.filter_by(project_id=request_json["project_id"],
                                                 name=request_json["variant_name"]).first()
        print(f'Now updateing Variant:{request_json["variant_name"]} in Project ID:{request_json["project_id"]}\n'
              f' Key:{request_json["bdf_file_key"]} Value:{request_json["bdf_file_name"]}')
        print("File before edit contains:")
        print("\n".join(variant_object.bdf_files))
        variant_object.bdf_files[request_json["bdf_file_key"]] = request_json["bdf_file_name"]
        print("File after contains:")
        print("\n".join(variant_object.bdf_files))
        db.session.commit()
        print("File after database Commit contains:")
        print("\n".join(variant_object.bdf_files))
        return json.dumps({'success': True}), 200, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}
```

As soon as I start the  flask-server in default threaded=True not all database updates are committed correctly as some start with an old outdated version. Threaded=False does work but I dont want an unresponsive Server when Updates are made.

I am using a sqlite Database with I initiate with Flask-SQLAlchemy v2.4.4 and I used Flask v1.1.2

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f"sqlite:///{DATABASE_PATH}"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Sessions should be scoped and prevent this issue with requests and Flask-Sqlalchemy or should they not?

Here is what I tried and failed with threaded=True.
I tried accessing the Database directly within the threads.
I tried accessing the Database directly within the threads with "with app.app_context():"
I tried creating Session objects inside the threads and removing them after

My Question now: How do I make sure that multiple requests do not override data with Flask-SQLAlchemy? Can I force a merge somehow?

Here is some example log to illustrate the issue. In they each new request should have one additional line. At the end there should be 8 keys in the dictionary. Sometimes I have only 2. ;-(

Hopefully someone can help me!
That would be much appreciated. :-)

```
2021-04-22 17:39:42 eveci068 werkzeug[18966] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021 17:39:42] "GET /process_status HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Now updateing Variant:30 in Project ID:1
 Key:Model_Assembly.assembly_rollgeraeusch_animation Value:/home/xxx/.ASPT/Projects/Test1/30/Standardrechnungen/Test1_Rollgeraeusch_Animation_30_20210422-173943.bdf
File before edit contains:
File after contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_rollgeraeusch_animation
Now updateing Variant:30 in Project ID:1
 Key:Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg Value:/home/xxx/.ASPT/Projects/Test1/30/Standardrechnungen/Test1_Empfindlichkeiten_rg_30_20210422-173943.bdf
File before edit contains:
File after contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
File after database Commit contains:
2021-04-22 17:39:43 eveci068 werkzeug[18966] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021 17:39:43] "POST /update_database_objects HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-04-22 17:39:43 eveci068 apscheduler.executors.default[18966] INFO Job "152 (trigger: date[2021-04-22 17:39:38 CEST], next run at: 2021-04-22 17:39:38 CEST)" executed successfully
2021-04-22 17:39:43 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Job: 152 finished!
2021-04-22 17:39:43 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Return Value: {'bdf_file_name': '/home/xxx/.ASPT/Projects/Test1/30/Standardrechnungen/Test1_Rollgeraeusch_Animation_30_20210422-173943.bdf'}
Model_Assembly.assembly_rollgeraeusch_animation
Response from Rollgeraeusche Animation Post: <Response [200]>
2021-04-22 17:39:44 eveci068 werkzeug[18966] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021 17:39:44] "POST /update_database_objects HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-04-22 17:39:44 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Response from Job_Error Post: <Response [200]>
File after database Commit contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Now updateing Variant:30 in Project ID:1
 Key:Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg Value:/home/xxx/.ASPT/Projects/Test1/30/Standardrechnungen/Test1_Empfindlichkeiten_mg_30_20210422-173944.bdf
File before edit contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
File after contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
Response from Akustische Empfindlichkeiten_RG Post: <Response [200]>
2021-04-22 17:39:44 eveci068 werkzeug[18966] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021 17:39:44] "POST /update_database_objects HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-04-22 17:39:44 eveci068 apscheduler.executors.default[18966] INFO Job "148 (trigger: date[2021-04-22 17:39:38 CEST], next run at: 2021-04-22 17:39:38 CEST)" executed successfully
2021-04-22 17:39:44 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Job: 148 finished!
2021-04-22 17:39:44 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Return Value: {'bdf_file_name': '/home/xxx/.ASPT/Projects/Test1/30/Standardrechnungen/Test1_Empfindlichkeiten_rg_30_20210422-173943.bdf'}
File after database Commit contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
Response from Akustische Empfindlichkeiten_MG Post: <Response [200]>
2021-04-22 17:39:44 eveci068 werkzeug[18966] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021 17:39:44] "POST /update_database_objects HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-04-22 17:39:44 eveci068 apscheduler.executors.default[18966] INFO Job "147 (trigger: date[2021-04-22 17:39:38 CEST], next run at: 2021-04-22 17:39:38 CEST)" executed successfully
2021-04-22 17:39:44 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Job: 147 finished!
2021-04-22 17:39:44 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Return Value: {'bdf_file_name': '/home/xxx/.ASPT/Projects/Test1/30/Standardrechnungen/Test1_Empfindlichkeiten_mg_30_20210422-173944.bdf'}
2021-04-22 17:39:45 eveci068 werkzeug[18966] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021 17:39:45] "POST /update_database_objects HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-04-22 17:39:45 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Response from Job_Error Post: <Response [200]>
Now updateing Variant:30 in Project ID:1
 Key:Model_Assembly.assembly_wellige_teerstrasse_animation Value:/home/xxx/.ASPT/Projects/Test1/30/Standardrechnungen/Test1_WT_Animation_30_20210422-173944.bdf
File before edit contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
File after contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
Model_Assembly.assembly_wellige_teerstrasse_animation
Now updateing Variant:30 in Project ID:1
 Key:Model_Assembly.assembly_wellige_teerstrasse Value:/home/xxx/.ASPT/Projects/Test1/30/Standardrechnungen/Test1_WelligeTeerstrasse_30_20210422-173944.bdf
File before edit contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
File after contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
Model_Assembly.assembly_wellige_teerstrasse
2021-04-22 17:39:46 eveci068 werkzeug[18966] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021 17:39:46] "POST /update_database_objects HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-04-22 17:39:46 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Response from Job_Error Post: <Response [200]>
Now updateing Variant:30 in Project ID:1
 Key:Model_Assembly.assembly_motorgeraeusch Value:/home/xxx/.ASPT/Projects/Test1/30/Standardrechnungen/Test1_Motorgeraeusch_30_20210422-173945.bdf
File before edit contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
File after contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
Model_Assembly.assembly_motorgeraeusch
File after database Commit contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
Model_Assembly.assembly_motorgeraeusch
Response from Motorgeraeusche Post: <Response [200]>
2021-04-22 17:39:46 eveci068 werkzeug[18966] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021 17:39:46] "POST /update_database_objects HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-04-22 17:39:46 eveci068 apscheduler.executors.default[18966] INFO Job "150 (trigger: date[2021-04-22 17:39:38 CEST], next run at: 2021-04-22 17:39:38 CEST)" executed successfully
2021-04-22 17:39:46 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Job: 150 finished!
2021-04-22 17:39:46 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Return Value: {'bdf_file_name': '/home/xxx/.ASPT/Projects/Test1/30/Standardrechnungen/Test1_Motorgeraeusch_30_20210422-173945.bdf'}
Now updateing Variant:30 in Project ID:1
 Key:Model_Assembly.assembly_rollgeraeusch Value:/home/xxx/.ASPT/Projects/Test1/30/Standardrechnungen/Test1_Rollgeraeusch_30_20210422-173946.bdf
File before edit contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
Model_Assembly.assembly_motorgeraeusch
File after contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
Model_Assembly.assembly_motorgeraeusch
Model_Assembly.assembly_rollgeraeusch
2021-04-22 17:39:46 eveci068 werkzeug[18966] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021 17:39:46] "POST /update_database_objects HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-04-22 17:39:46 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Response from Job_Error Post: <Response [200]>
File after database Commit contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
Model_Assembly.assembly_wellige_teerstrasse
Response from Wellige Teerstraße Post: <Response [200]>
2021-04-22 17:39:47 eveci068 werkzeug[18966] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021 17:39:47] "POST /update_database_objects HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-04-22 17:39:47 eveci068 apscheduler.executors.default[18966] INFO Job "153 (trigger: date[2021-04-22 17:39:38 CEST], next run at: 2021-04-22 17:39:38 CEST)" executed successfully
2021-04-22 17:39:47 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Job: 153 finished!
2021-04-22 17:39:47 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Return Value: {'bdf_file_name': '/home/xxx/.ASPT/Projects/Test1/30/Standardrechnungen/Test1_WelligeTeerstrasse_30_20210422-173944.bdf'}
2021-04-22 17:39:47 eveci068 werkzeug[18966] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021 17:39:47] "POST /update_database_objects HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-04-22 17:39:47 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Response from Job_Error Post: <Response [200]>
Now updateing Variant:30 in Project ID:1
 Key:Model_Assembly.assembly_leerlauf Value:/home/xxx/.ASPT/Projects/Test1/30/Standardrechnungen/Test1_Leerlauf_30_20210422-173946.bdf
File before edit contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
Model_Assembly.assembly_wellige_teerstrasse
File after contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
Model_Assembly.assembly_wellige_teerstrasse
Model_Assembly.assembly_leerlauf
File after database Commit contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
Model_Assembly.assembly_wellige_teerstrasse_animation
Response from Wellige Teerstraße Animation Post: <Response [200]>
2021-04-22 17:39:47 eveci068 werkzeug[18966] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021 17:39:47] "POST /update_database_objects HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-04-22 17:39:47 eveci068 apscheduler.executors.default[18966] INFO Job "154 (trigger: date[2021-04-22 17:39:38 CEST], next run at: 2021-04-22 17:39:38 CEST)" executed successfully
2021-04-22 17:39:47 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Job: 154 finished!
2021-04-22 17:39:47 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Return Value: {'bdf_file_name': '/home/xxx/.ASPT/Projects/Test1/30/Standardrechnungen/Test1_WT_Animation_30_20210422-173944.bdf'}
2021-04-22 17:39:48 eveci068 werkzeug[18966] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021 17:39:48] "POST /update_database_objects HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-04-22 17:39:48 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Response from Job_Error Post: <Response [200]>
File after database Commit contains:
2021-04-22 17:39:48 eveci068 werkzeug[18966] INFO 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2021 17:39:48] "POST /update_database_objects HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2021-04-22 17:39:48 eveci068 apscheduler.executors.default[18966] INFO Job "151 (trigger: date[2021-04-22 17:39:38 CEST], next run at: 2021-04-22 17:39:38 CEST)" executed successfully
2021-04-22 17:39:48 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Job: 151 finished!
2021-04-22 17:39:48 eveci068 aspt_web.run[18966] INFO Return Value: {'bdf_file_name': '/home/xxx/.ASPT/Projects/Test1/30/Standardrechnungen/Test1_Rollgeraeusch_30_20210422-173946.bdf'}
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
Model_Assembly.assembly_motorgeraeusch
Model_Assembly.assembly_rollgeraeusch
Response from Rollgeraeusch Post: <Response [200]>
File after database Commit contains:
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_rg
Model_Assembly.assembly_akustische_empfindlichkeiten_mg
Model_Assembly.assembly_wellige_teerstrasse
Model_Assembly.assembly_leerlauf
Response from Leerlauf Post: <Response [200]>
```

Kind regards!

Comment: As an update, I use relationships instead of PickleType Dictionaries and Lists for "Thread Sensitive Data". It works a lot better.
I still get Database Lock errors sometime, when a secondary thread access the SQLite Database. So the problem is not completely solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know your specific details into what data you're storing-- but I think you're generally asking how can you maintain consistency within a database, for example, lets say you had a table 'AccountBalances' and account #1 has $20,000.

You then run ten processes all at once to add $1000 to that account.  There's a number of ways to write those processes:

### Option 1 (the bad way):

- Read the existing value ($20,000) calculate the new value ($21,000) and then send an update to the database with the new value (`set balance = $21,000`)

The problem is, if all processes ran at the exact same time, they would each read $20,000 as the current balance and then you'd end up with $21,000 instead of the expected $30,000, or somewhere inbetween.

### Option 2 (the better way):

Never tell the database the expected value-- just tell it the incremental amount. Instead of telling the database `set balance = $21,000` tell it `set balance = balance + $1,000` and let the database handle the multiple requests (you may well need a more complete dbms then sqlite for that)

### Option 3 (the auditable way):

Store the data in a ledger-- instead of an account balance, store just the transactions:

```
+$1,000 into account #1 from process #2 on 2021-04-22 @ 13:34
+$1,000 into account #1 from process #1 on 2021-04-22 @ 13:34
+$1,000 into account #1 from process #4 on 2021-04-22 @ 13:35
```

Then have some other view resolve the actual balance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply!

I am using a SQLAlchemy DB Object called PickleType. It just stores a python dictionary as some sort of hexcode so you dont have to manually json load / dump on accessing the value.

I am not sure if I can update the dictionary within SQLAlchemy with a single database request. That could work. I might switch back to storing the dictionary as a plain string but even then I dont know how I would add to the json string with plain SQLite...

Your ideas gave me some though. I could just use a relationship. I then just add the new entries to the db.